# Where to put configuration in a bndtools/maven project?

Tags: maven, osgi, properties-file, bnd

I have project where I use the bnd-maven-plugin from the bndtools project. I've tried to follow the conventions from the enRoute OSGI maven tutorial. So, I have a parent directory with a module pom, and a subdirectory for each bundle, and one for packaging and running the whole thing (with the bndrun file).

Question is, how do I pass configuration? Previously, when I built the bundles with the (felix) maven-bundle-plugin, I would drop the bundles in the deploy folder in Karaf, and make a file for the PID in the config directory, but I can't do that when building a standalone jar - or at least I can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuration is independent from bndtools and bnd-maven-plugin.

The way to provide configuration depends on the installed configuration admin impl. If you install felix config admin and fileinstall then you can supply the configuration in a config folder like you are used to.

For an example see the [osgi-chat example](https://github.com/cschneider/osgi-chat/). It is built with maven, the bundles are created with bnd-maven-plugin and the runnable jar is created using bndtools.

Felix config admin and file install are configured [in rsa.bndrun](https://github.com/cschneider/osgi-chat/blob/master/packaging/rsa.bndrun).